# How to compare equity between Scala reflection library type `universe.Type` and an ordinary type?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm practicing to use Scala reflection features, I get this result:

```
res46: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.List[String]
```

How to test the result value see if it represents a `List[String]`?

In another word, how to test whether a `universe.Type` represents a specified ordinary Scala type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val tpe: Type = ???

//type equivalence test (is tpe exactly List[String]?)
tpe =:= typeOf[List[String]]

//type conformance test (is tpe a subtype of List[String]?)
tpe <:< typeOf[List[String]]
```